# group by result of subquery

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I am trying to use the results of a subquery in my Group By statement, and have found that this is not allowed. I think it may be possible to do this with a CTE, but I'm not sure exactly. I am creating this SQL code for a SQL Server 2005. I am obviously no expert.  Here is the SQL statement I wrote...

```
select
  sum(paxon), 
  (select id from runs as RS where RS.code = RL.runsegment) as port_id,
  date
from
  runlogs as RL
where 
  date BETWEEN '07/09/2012' and '07/16/2012'     
  and account in ('311,312,313')
  and runsegment in (select code from runsegments where org_id = 13)
group by
  date,
  port_id
```

When I try to run this I am told that port_id is an invalid column name. I am pretty sure that this is possible to do by creating a temporary table or CTE or possibly using a JOIN, but I am not sure how to do so. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I mistyped the top portid. All instances read "port_id"

Comment: Have you tried `...group by date, (select id from runs as RS where RS.code = RL.runsegment)`? (Not that it would be optimal I guess) Also, I would use `[date]`, not `date`.

Comment: Tells me "Cannot use an aggregate or a subquery in an expression used for the group by list of a GROUP BY clause"

Comment: Was afraid it would't work. Was worth a shot though :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this?  Unless I am missing something, I don't see a need for a subquery.

```
SELECT SUM(rl.paxon)
    ,r.id AS port_id
    ,rl.[date]
FROM runlogs rl
    INNER JOIN runs r
        ON r.code = rl.runsegment
    INNER JOIN runsegments rs
        ON rs.code = rl.runsegment
WHERE rl.[date] BETWEEN '20120709' AND '20120716'  
    AND rl.account in ('311','312','313')
    AND rs.org_id = 13
GROUP BY rl.[date], r.id
```

I'm not sure what `account in ('311,312,313')` is attempting to do.  In my answer, I assumed that `account` was either `nvarchar` or `varchar` and that each of the three items are actually different `account` values.  If `account` is an `int`, then the line should be:  `AND rl.account in (311,312,313)`.

I also changed your dates to use the preferred [unseparated numeric strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191307%28SQL.90%29.aspx).

Comment: YES!!! Thanks do much for the help! I have been putting off learning JOINS as I am only a very part time coder, but this was a nice kick in the pants to get a move on with it. Even added another join of my own to get the names of the ports from a third table and it worked!

Comment: Glad to hear it and good luck! Don't forget to accept the answer.  :)

Answer (score 0):

One option is the below

```
select sum(sum_paxon), date, port_id from
(
select paxon,

(select id from runs as RS where RS.code = RL.runsegment) as port_id,

date from runlogs as RL

where

date BETWEEN '07/09/2012' and '07/16/2012'

and account in ('311,312,313')

and runsegment in (select code from runsegments where org_id = 13)
 ) Z
group by date, port_id
```